# Seaborn Stripplot with Min, Mid, Max lines

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to create `strip plot` from seaborn and adding lines indicating the Min, Mid, and Max that I set. I would like to set the Min line at the 500 mark, the mid at 2000 and the max line at 3500.

My goal is to display which points are within the min and max and which ones are outside of the range. I tried playing with a mixed boxplot and strip plot, but the boxplot only shows lines for the percentile of the data set.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data = DataFrame([1000,2000,3000,4000, 8000], columns=["Amount"], index=["EE1","EE2","EE3","EE4", "EE5"])

sns.boxplot(data = data)
sns.stripplot(data=data, size=6, jitter=True)
```

I get something like this:

[image]

So, instead of the lines from the boxplot, is there a way to add lines to mark the  500, 2000, and 3500 values?

The image I edited is what I'm trying to get to:

[image]